# Replacing characters in String using Meta characters or character classes

Tags: java, regex

I am writing to remove all non-alphanumeric characters in a String with only lowercase letters.

I am using the replaceAll function and have looked at a few regexes

My reference is from: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html which shows that

- \s : A whitespace character, short for [ \t\n\x0b\r\f]
- \W : A non-word character [^\w]

I tried the folllowing in Java but the results didn't remove the spaces or symbols:

`lowercased = lowercased.replaceAll("\\W\\s", "");`

output:

`amanaplanac analp anam a`

May I know what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex `\W\s` means *"a non-word character **followed by** a whitespace character"*.

If you want to replace any character that is one of those, use one of these:

- `\W|\s` where `|` means *or*
- `[\W\s]` where `[ ]` is a *character class* that in this case merges the built-in special character classes `\W` and `\s`, because that's what those are.

Of the two, I recommend using the second.

---

Of course, having `\s` there is redundant, because `\s` means whitespace character, and `\W` means non-word character, and since whitespaces are not word characters, using `\W` alone is enough.

```java
lowercased = lowercased.replaceAll("\\W+", "");
```

Comment: also instead of replacing each character, replacing them altogether using `\W+` makes sense. this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `|` (or operator) like `\W|\s` since both `\W` and `\s` are independent case for which you want to replace. And since whitespace are not word character you can use `\W` only.

```
lowercased = lowercased.replaceAll("\\W|\\s", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex `\W` is meant for matching character's that are not numbers(`0-9`), alphabets(`A-Z` and `a-z`) and underscore (`_`). And `/s` is meant for matching space.

As `/W` already take care for matching non alphanumeric characters (excluding underscore). No need to use `\s`.

So if you are using `\W` you are allowing underscore(`_`) with alphanumeric values.

use the following to exclude underscore as well.

```
lowercased = lowercased.replaceAll("\\W|_", "");
```